# MySQLi prepare result not as expected

Tags: php, database, mysqli, prepare

I am trying to retrieve one result from my database table 'members' using a prepared call.

```
$favid = 1;
$type = "favdeal";
$action = 1;
$user_id = 1;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM members WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $type, $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($favs);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    print($favs);
}
$stmt->close();
```

This is the only way i managed to get any kind of result.

The table has a column called 'favdeal' which has a value of '2' in it.
The result printed returns the name of the column not the value.

**So my question is how do i get the value '2' instead of the name of the column?**

Comment: You can't bind tables and columns `SELECT ?` period. Select an actual column. Or do `SELECT $type` if you want to use a variable.

Comment: Ah thanks, i didn't realize i couldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind columns (*or tables*) from doing a `SELECT` as you have in `SELECT ?`.

- Select an actual column.

Or, if you want to do it dynamically, you need to use a variable.

Example: `SELECT $type` <= that is allowed.

*However*, column names can be binded when using a `WHERE` clause.

Example: `SELECT column FROM table WHERE column=?`
which you are presently using => `WHERE id=?`

Consult the manual on `bind_param()`

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php**

---

**Footnotes:**

If you happen to use an MySQL reserved word (*it could happen*), you will need to wrap your column's variable with backticks.

For example: (if using `$type="from";`) "from" being a reserved word.

```
SELECT `$type` FROM members WHERE id=?
```

For a list of MySQL reserved words, visit the following page:

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**